# django: messages.add_message not displaying in html page

Tags: django, django-email

I have a Django library application, wherein I have a book_detail page in which the user can download/email the book's pdf link to himself.

On sending such an email(which is working perfectly, the email is being received), **I want to display a pop-up or an alert message on that same html page instead of redirecting to some other page.**

Here is the views.py code:

```
def send_email(request):

try:
    send_mail('Book request', 'email body', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['xyz@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)

    #this message is not getting displayed in the same html page
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Email sent successfully.')

except EmailMessage:
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Error has occurred')
```

HTML page book_detail.html code:

```
  ......
  rest of the code....

  {% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

I use a submit button click to send an email:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name='index'),
   ......
   path('email_book/', views.send_email, name='email_book'),
 ]
```

The error occuring:

[image: ValueError]

**Please suggest what should be done, is there any other solution I can try for displaying an alert box/message on that same html page, without redirecting it to any other page.**

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Since there is a complex url routing inherent for book_detail.html page, django messages do get displayed when I used it in some other html page:

```
 def otherpage(request):
    ....
    messages.add_message(...)
    return render(request, 'other_page.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

The view function in Django should always return some `Response`  object

```
def send_email(request):

  try:
    send_mail('Book request', 'email body', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['xyz@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)

    #this message is not getting displayed in the same html page
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Email sent successfully.')

  except smtplib.SMTPException:
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Error has occurred')
  return render(request, 'book_detail.html', {
    'messages': messages,
  }, content_type='text/html')
```

Comment: I have included your code, it is giving me the following error: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

Comment: @Simran looks like your exception `EmailMessage` does not inherit from `Exception` class. that should fix the problem

Comment: ok so what exceptionclass should I replace 'EmailMessage' with? although the email are being correctly sent/received

Comment: @Simran I also have updated the code, so you need to render your own template for the page where you want to see messages

Comment: @Simran look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#send-mail while I will update my answer.

Comment: nope it gives me this error: NoReverseMatch at /catalog/email_book/

Comment: but when i remove the 'content_type' = 'application/html' from the render(), the message gets displayed. Although not in book_detail, but I used the same code in another html page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185005/discussion-between-py-dude-and-simran).